# Running MongoDB as service on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, ext4, mongodb

I'm trying to get mongoDB run under Arch.
However, I'm only able to start it as root or using `systemctl` with the default path.

What I'm trying to do is to change the default data path from

```
/data/db
```

to

```
/home/manuel/ExtDrive/Data/mongodb
```

and run it using `systemctl`.

As ExtDrive indicates, this is an ext4 formatted drive connected via SATA (not USB).

As soon as I change the path in my mongoconfig, the service starts failing:

```
mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-01-11 19:45:56 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 29468 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 29468 (code=exited, status=100)

Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.311+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.311+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.311+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/home/manuel/ExtDrive/Data/mongodb/", jo>
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.312+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /home/manuel/ExtDrive/Data/mongodb/: b>
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.312+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.312+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.312+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner mongod[29468]: 2019-01-11T19:45:56.312+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Jan 11 19:45:56 Rechner systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Permissions for the directory are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb daemon 4.0K Jan 11 19:37 mongodb
```

Here is my mongo config:

```
storage:

  dbPath: "/home/manuel/ExtDrive/Data/mongodb/"

  journal:

    enabled: true

net:

  port: 27017

  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Why does it run perfectly with the standard path, but stops working as soon as I specify an alternative path?

Comment: Firstly, the user directories inside of `/home` are not traversable by other users by default. Second, `selinux` can also be an issue. Last, is there a reason that you need the data to be in your home directory? You're increasing the risk of accidental deletion.

Comment: I am used to mount all my harddrives in /home since I have different harddrives for data, source code etc.
Mounting the harddrive under /mnt and symlinking the folders back to /home did the trick for me, however I'd still rather mount the drive in /home

Comment: What does it matter that they're different? Just create different directories in `/mnt` and put them there like you've already done.